# Updating trigger (how)

Tags: plsql, sql-update, alter, eventtrigger

can someone help with updating a trigger? I know I am supposed to use the alter clause but after that I am stuck. I would like to alter this trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER  "CR_SURGERY_AUDIT"  
before insert or delete or update on CR_SURGERY
for each row
declare 
V_user varchar2 (30);
V_date varchar2 (30); 
begin 
select user, to_char(sysdate, 'dd/mon/yyyy hh24:mi:SS') INTO v_user, v_date
from dual;
IF inserting THEN
insert into CR_SURGERY_AUDIT (new_name, old_name, user_name, entry_date, operation)
VALUES (:NEW.CR_SURGERY, NULL, v_user, v_date, 'insert');
ELSIF DELETING THEN
insert into CR_SURGERY_AUDIT (new_name, old_name, user_name, entry_date, operation)
VALUES (null, :OLD.CR_SURGERY, v_user, v_date, 'delete');
ELSIF UPDATING THEN
insert into CR_SURGERY_AUDIT (new_name, old_name, user_name, entry_date, operation)
VALUES (:NEW.CR_SURGERY, :OLD.CR_SURGERY, v_user, v_date, 'Update');
END IF;
END;
```

I know it's simple but I cannot find a way to compose it. I want to add FK_SOCRD_ID so it updates to:

```
select user, to_char(sysdate, 'dd/mon/yyyy') INTO v_user, v_date from dual;
IF inserting THEN
insert into CR_SURGERY_AUDIT (new_name, old_name, user_name, entry_date,
operation, FK_SOCRD_ID)  
VALUES (:NEW.CR_SURGERY, NULL, v_user, v_date, 'insert');
```

Comment: `create or replace trigger` already replaces an existing trigger with your new code. Or you can just drop and recreate it.

Comment: Aw man. Okay. I did read that most likely I'll have to drop and recreate it but was hoping there was another work around to just updating it.

Comment: By the way you don’t need the `select ... into ... from dual` as PL/SQL has a handy `:=` assignment operator :) Also `user` will always be the name of the trigger owner. Maybe `sys_context(‘userenv’,’os_user’)` will be more useful for auditing.

Comment: Hi William,
How would I write that? Sorry I am new to this. If you don't mind :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no syntax to modify triggers, you just modify your `create or replace trigger` code and rerun it.

With your proposed change, I make it something like this:

```
create or replace trigger cr_surgery_audit
before insert or delete or update on cr_surgery
for each row
declare
    k_user constant cr_surgery_audit.user_name%type := sys_context('userenv','os_user');
    k_date constant cr_surgery_audit.entry_date%type := sysdate;
begin
    if inserting then
        insert into cr_surgery_audit (new_name, old_name, user_name, entry_date, operation, fk_socrd_id)  
        values (:new.cr_surgery, null, k_user, k_date, 'insert', 12345);
    elsif deleting then
        insert into cr_surgery_audit (new_name, old_name, user_name, entry_date, operation)
        values (null, :old.cr_surgery, k_user, k_date, 'delete');
    elsif updating then
        insert into cr_surgery_audit (new_name, old_name, user_name, entry_date, operation)
        values (:new.cr_surgery, :old.cr_surgery, k_user, k_date, 'update');
    end if;
end;
```

I've assumed `cr_surgery_audit.entry_date` is actually a `date` and not a `varchar2`.

You need a value to populate `fk_socrd_id` with, so I put in 123456 as a dummy value.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you sir!